# Optimise database high score ranking in arcade game

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to add an online high-score table to my basic iOS app. I don't want it to be associated with GameCenter, so I want to store the high scores in my own database. When the users first open the app, they are prompted to enter a nickname for themselves which the highscores are saved under. In theory, the high score database would look like this:

```
userid  name      highscore
1       james123  201       
2       xXsamXx   98
```

Where `userid` is auto-incrementing, `name` is their chosen nickname, and `highscore` is the highest score they have achieved, which is overwritten each time they break said score.

To return a user's global rank in-game, I could `ORDER` the database by high-score and return their position.

**This poses two issues that I want to solve** - I don't want the entire database reordered whenever anyone gets a high score, and I'm also not sure how to return the same rank for two users with identical scores (as one column, i.e. user, will ultimately come before the other). How could I solve these two issues?

Thanks!

Comment: What about `LIMIT` ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: 'Entire database reordered' Eh? Rows in tables in relational databases have no 'order'

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about "re-ordering" your table - `ORDER BY` only reorders the *result* of your query, not the table itself.

If you want to return the rank as well, you'll need to add a `rank` field to your table, as you must anyway use two separate rows for two identical scores. You can populate this field right after you update the `highscore` field.

Comment: Or if two scores are equal and there are no other meaningful criteria then you could order those results by something arbitrary, like the alphabetical order of the name. This is done by adding a second field name to the ORDER by clause.

Comment: The reason I didn't want to create a rank column was because a user's rank would change if another user beat them. How could I return a user's current rank without ordering every single logged score each time a new high score is reached?